# Change colors in devexpress charts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am drawing a pie chart using Devexpress in my MVC project.

While doing it by default my chart generated with three colors, as below

but my client is not satisfied, with the colors of it and wanted me to change them which match with our application background, so please help me, how to do this.

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code.

```
    settings.Name = "chart";
    settings.Width = 600;
    settings.Height = 250;
    settings.BorderOptions.Visible = false;

    Series series1 = new Series("Type", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Pie3D);
    settings.Series.Add(series1);
    series1.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;
    series1.ArgumentDataMember = "ClassName";
    series1.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
    series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "PercentageValues" });


    series1.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;
    series1.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;
    series1.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
    series1.Label.ResolveOverlappingMode = ResolveOverlappingMode.Default;
    series1.Label.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the following code. I have successfully implemented the same for giving custom color for rangebar. I guess it will work for your case also

```
 settings.CustomDrawSeriesPoint = (s, ev) =>
    {
        BarDrawOptions drawOptions = ev.SeriesDrawOptions as BarDrawOptions;

        if (drawOptions == null)
            return;

        Color colorInTarget = Color.Blue;
        double x = ev.SeriesPoint.Values[0];
        double y = ev.SeriesPoint.Values[1];


        if (x == 0)
        {  //Do starting
            colorInTarget = Color.FromArgb(159,125, 189);
        }
        else{
            //Red - price Increase
            // Green price Decrease
            if (y > previousYValue)
            {
                colorInTarget = Color.Red; ;
            }
            else
            {
                colorInTarget = Color.Green;
            }
        }


        previousYValue = y;

        drawOptions.Color = colorInTarget;
        drawOptions.FillStyle.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
        drawOptions.Border.Color = Color.Transparent;



    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the theme and palette properties of the chart control. follow the links below to devexpress documentation. although the examples refers to winform application they are still avaliable in asp.net mvc controls.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument7433
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5538

```
    // Define the chart's appearance and palette.
barChart.AppearanceName = "Dark";
barChart.PaletteName = "Opulent";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private List<StudentClass.ChartsPointsSummary> GetStudentSummaryResults()
            {
                var StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["StudentID"]);

                var StudentDetailsP = CtxSM.SMISGet_StudentAttendanceDetailsByStudentId(StudentId, SessionDataManager.SessionData.LoginUserId, SessionDataManager.SessionData.AcademicYearID, SessionDataManager.SessionData.BusinessUnitId, ref outError).ToList();
                var Presents = StudentDetailsP.Select(p => new { p.Months, p.Presents});
                var CountsP = StudentDetailsP.Count();
                List<StudentClass.ChartsPointsSummary> MT = new List<StudentClass.ChartsPointsSummary>();
                foreach (var ab in Presents)
                {
                    MT.Add(new StudentClass.ChartsPointsSummary { PresentSummaryX = ab.Months, PresentSummaryY = Convert.ToInt32(ab.Presents) });
                }

                var StudentDetailsA = CtxSM.SMISGet_StudentAttendanceDetailsByStudentId(StudentId, SessionDataManager.SessionData.LoginUserId, SessionDataManager.SessionData.AcademicYearID, SessionDataManager.SessionData.BusinessUnitId, ref outError).ToList();
                var Absents = StudentDetailsP.Select(p => new { p.Months, p.Absents });
                var CountsA = StudentDetailsA.Count();
                foreach (var ab in Absents)
                {
                    MT.Add(new StudentClass.ChartsPointsSummary { AbsentSummaryX = ab.Months, AbsentSummaryY = Convert.ToInt32(ab.Absents) });
                }

                var StudentDetailsL = CtxSM.SMISGet_StudentAttendanceDetailsByStudentId(StudentId, SessionDataManager.SessionData.LoginUserId, SessionDataManager.SessionData.AcademicYearID, SessionDataManager.SessionData.BusinessUnitId, ref outError).ToList();
                var CountL = StudentDetailsL.Count();
                var Leaves = StudentDetailsP.Select(p => new { p.Months, p.Leaves });
                foreach (var ab in Leaves)
                {
                    MT.Add(new StudentClass.ChartsPointsSummary { LeaveSummaryX = ab.Months, LeaveSummaryY = Convert.ToInt32(ab.Leaves) });
                }
                return MT;
            }


@Html.DevExpress().Chart(settings =>
{

    settings.Name = "SummaryDetailsById";

    settings.Width = 1032;
    settings.Height = 250;

    Series chartSeries = new Series("Presents", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Bar);
    chartSeries.ArgumentDataMember = "PresentSummaryX";
    chartSeries.ValueDataMembers[0] = "PresentSummaryY";
    settings.Series.Add(chartSeries);

    Series chartSeries2 = new Series("Absents", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Bar);
    chartSeries2.ArgumentDataMember = "AbsentSummaryX";
    chartSeries2.ValueDataMembers[0] = "AbsentSummaryY";
    settings.Series.Add(chartSeries2);

    Series chartSeries3 = new Series("Leaves", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Bar);
    chartSeries3.ArgumentDataMember = "LeaveSummaryX";
    chartSeries3.ValueDataMembers[0] = "LeaveSummaryY";
    settings.Series.Add(chartSeries3);

    settings.CrosshairEnabled = DefaultBoolean.Default;
    settings.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    settings.BorderOptions.Visibility = DefaultBoolean.True;

    settings.Titles.Add(new ChartTitle()
    {
        Text = "Student Attendance Summary"
    });

    XYDiagram diagram = ((XYDiagram)settings.Diagram);
    diagram.AxisX.Label.Angle = -30;
    diagram.AxisY.Interlaced = true;

}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```